# How can i remove the blank white space of left and right side from the blospot theme (Cyber)?

Tags: html, css, themes, blogger

I am using a blogspot theme name **Cyber**. In this theme i have got a problem and that is in the home page there are blank white space in the right and left both side. Now how can i remove that space?

Comment: I think it is css problem. Share your code.

Answer (score 0):

use *{margin:0px;padding:0px} in your style